# How make formatted string by string resources

Tags: c#, string, format, resources

I want use a string for my Exception message:

`$"Your file size cannot exceeded from {AppSetting.MaxFileSize}"`

But I want to put this in a ResourceFile:

`"ExceededFileSizeException": $"Your file size cannot exceeded from {AppSetting.MaxFileSize}"`

What is the best way to make this string and read it from code?

Answer (score 2):

That is a quite new representation of a string format command. If you are moving this string as it is to a resource file, the compiler won't format it later (im sure you are already getting compile time problems as the context is getting unknown - where should the input AppSetting.MaxFileSize come from?).

The "classical" algo is:

```
string.Format("Your file size cannot exceeded from {0}", AppSetting.MaxFileSize)
```

If formatting this way, you could move the template string into a resourcefile, the format method will then do the same magic.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I usually do

```
var templateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string yourSetting = "mysettings";
//templateDictionary.Add("AppSetting.MaxFileSize", AppSetting.MaxFileSize); // sample
templateDictionary.Add("AppSetting.MaxFileSize", yourSetting);

var inputText = "Your file size cannot exceeded from {AppSetting.MaxFileSize}";
var text = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"\{(.+?)\}", m => templateDictionary["AppSetting.MaxFileSize"]);
```

I create an extension method that can replace the variable inside a resource file string.

Comment: Well, it may work, but you are introducing new dependencies (a dictionary), are calling potentially expensive Regex methods and are loosing compiler safety (if "AppSetting.MaxFile" is incorrectly registered , you won't notice until it is needed at runtime; if using constants, you will not be able to compile if not spelling the name right).